# "Film" verhält sich zu "Verfilmung" wie "Computerspiel" zu..?

Tags: single-word-request, noun, phrase-request, analogy

Wenn ein Film produziert wird, der auf einer Literaturvorlage, Comic, Computerspiel etc. basiert, dann nennt man das "Verfilmung". Wie nennt man analog das Produzieren eines Computerspiels, das z.B. auf einem Film basiert?

Comment: **Merchandising** (T-Shirts, Spielzeug, *Computerspiel*, ...)

Answer (score 8):

Umsetzung als Computerspiel, Computerspielumsetzung

Adaption als Computerspiel, Computerspieladaption (nach @Wrzprmft)

Answer (score 6):

Computerspiel-Adaption

Das ist auch der einzige mir bekannte Begriff für Adaptionen in andere Medien als Film.

Comment: Ja, aber ohne den Kontext könnte es sich hier auch um die Adaption eines Computerspiels als etwas anderes (Film, Buch, ...) handeln. Zumindest meinem eigenen Gefühl nach.

Answer (score 2):

Das Wort *Lizenzversoftung* ist auch nicht unüblich. Dabei handelt es sich um einen herabwertenden Begriff, der die oft schlechte Qualität von Spielen, die auf Filmlizenzen basieren, anprangert.

Comment: Mal abgesehen davon, dass sich "Versoftung" zumindest vom Begriff her auf jede Art von Software beziehen kann, nicht nur auf (die aus Filmen/Büchern sicher häufig hervorgehenden) Spiele.