# Is there a word for a book adapted to a comic? Similar to “Comicverfilmung”?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

I’m looking for a word that may or may not exist.  The German word for a comic adapted to a film is *Comicverfilmung* (for regular books it’s *Buchverfilmung*).  I am looking for the word for a book adapted into a comic, for example the graphic-novel versions of the Game of Thrones book series.  I have had no luck so far, and am now just hoping that there is a word for it.  Also, if not how would one go about saying that there is a comic version of a book?

Comment: Verwursten. SCNR.

Comment: Be careful with throwing comics and graphic novels into one category. I have met people who are very insistent about the difference.

Comment: Related: [“Film” verhält sich zu “Verfilmung” wie “Computerspiel” zu..?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/6743/2594)

Answer (score 5):

The first word that came to my mind was *Comic-Version* - and indeed: Amazon gives some dozens hits for this search term that appear to be the kind of comic you are after. The term itself does not communicate that the original was a book, so you'd have to put this in the phrase if needed, like "Comic-Version eines Romans von X.Y." or "Comic-Version von *Krieg und Frieden*".

Comment: Thank you very much, this is just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Chandra Thank you - glad I could help. You might consider accepting the answer then - see http://german.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5):

*Comicadaption*

*Adaption* works for almost anything, but just includes the target medium – or, ambiguously, the source medium. You would include the original medium as a genitive attribute: *Filmadaption des Romans*, *Musicaladaption des Videospiels*, *Bühnenadaption des Dramas* … In some cases, *Version* works, too, but it somewhat assumes equal authoritative status of several versions.

The word also describes the actual relation much better, usually, because the medium shapes the content, i.e. many parts are omitted, added or changed (“re-imagined”).

If you’re looking for a less foreign term, native *Umsetzung* is also an option: *Comicumsetzung*.

Comment: Uhm... the common meaning of "Comicadaption" is "based on a comic", not "made into a comic"

Comment: @Emanuel Hm, you’re right that this is a possible and perhaps more common meaning of the compound when used without the attribute. I’ll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I'll throw "das Comic zum Buch" in the ring.

Answer (score 2):

I ran a search and found an article:

http://www.tagesspiegel.de/kultur/comics/kordon-klassiker-als-comic-zwischen-krieg-und-frieden/973796.html

> Jetzt haben sich zwei Comic-Autoren daran gemacht, das mehrfach ausgezeichnete Werk als *Bildgeschichte umzusetzen*. Mit Erfolg: Der Szenaristin Gerlinde Althoff und dem Zeichner Christoph Heuer ist eine beeindruckende Adaption des Klassikers gelungen.

"Umsetzung als Bildgeschichte" sounds a little bit more exalted than "comic", and "XY als Bildgeschichte" might be more fitting, depending on what XY is.

Comment: It might be that he just used the word to avoid using "comic" twice in one sentence "Comic-Autoren... Comic umzusetzen". That sounds kinda clumsy to my ears. So maybe that's why he or she chose Bildgeschichte... just an idea. Oh also, it might be that the intend was to avoid the "anglicism" graphic novel. In that case I would really go for "graphic novel" instead. I mean, we don't translate the Genres either (science fiction, fantasy, Thriller)

Comment: @Emanuel Roman, Novelle, Kurzgeschichte, Krimi, Groschenroman - we really don't translate genres???

Comment: @Matthias... 3 of those are forms rather than genres but I got your point. I should have said "certain genres"

Comment: @Emanuel Berechtigter Einwand. Ich habe als Nicht-LiWi auf die genaue Definition des Begriffs gar nicht geachtet. Möglicherweise gibt es aber auch keine, denn [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genre#Genres_der_Literatur) scheint mir zumindest bei 4 von 5 Begriffen Recht zu geben.